# PHP for comparing arrays, $_POST data and $_SESSION array

Tags: php, arrays, session, post, session-variables

So I've been stuck for a few hours trying to compare $_SESSION data stored as a variable with $_POST data from updated form fields but when I use array array_diff_assoc or array_diff i get either the whole session data array or the whole post data array(depending oh how I order them in the array function), and not the difference. I want to be able to output the difference only.

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM updatetest WHERE username = '{$username}' ";       
$select_users= mysqli_query($db, $query);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_users)) {
             $user_info['name'] =  $row['name'];
             $user_info['phone'] =  $row['phone'];
             $user_info['dob'] =  $row['dob'];
             $user_info['email'] =  $row['email'];
             $user_info['address_line_1'] = $row['address_line_1'];
             $user_info['town_city'] =  $row['town_city'];
             $user_info['postcode'] =  $row['postcode'];
             $your_data[]=$user_info;
               }
}
?> 

 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

         $name= $_POST['name'];
         $phone = $_POST['phone'];
         $dob = $_POST['dob'];
         $email = $_POST['email'];
         $address_line_1 = $_POST['address_line_1'];
         $town_city = $_POST['town_city'];
         $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];

$result = array_diff_assoc($_SESSION['your_data'],$_POST);
 print_r($result);
}

?>
```

Note: when I print_r either $_SESSION['your_data'] or $_POST, I can see the arrays. The goal is to send an email containing the form's updated fields using phpmail()

Comment: Could you cut out the extra variables, $user_info, under the sql statement and then just compare $row and $_post?

Comment: When I do that, there's no result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- i took some time to re-write your code to the best of my ability without having the same DB information as you.
- let me know if it works/errors! :)

key changes:

1. added 'MYSQLI_ASSOC' to 'mysqli_fetch_array'
2. changed:

```
'$your_data[] = $user_info;'
```

to

```
'_SESSION['your_data'] = $user_info;'
```

```
$_SESSION['username'] = 'userone';

if (!empty($_SESSION['username'])) {

  // $_SESSION variables are safely stored server side
  //$username = $_SESSION['username'];
  $select = '*';
  $table = 'updatetest';
  $column = $_SESSION['username'];

  $query = 'SELECT ' . $select . ' FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE username = ' . $column;
  //$query = "SELECT * FROM updatetest WHERE username = '{$username}' ";

  $select_users = mysqli_query($db, $query);

  /* associative array 
  * https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
  */
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_users, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    //while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_users)) {

    $user_info['name'] =  $row['name'];
    $user_info['phone'] =  $row['phone'];
    $user_info['dob'] =  $row['dob'];
    $user_info['email'] =  $row['email'];
    $user_info['address_line_1'] = $row['address_line_1'];
    $user_info['town_city'] =  $row['town_city'];
    $user_info['postcode'] =  $row['postcode'];
    //$your_data[] = $user_info;
    $_SESSION['your_data'] = $user_info;
  }
}

// form submission
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $dob = $_POST['dob'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $address_line_1 = $_POST['address_line_1'];
  $town_city = $_POST['town_city'];
  $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];

  $result = array_diff_assoc($_SESSION['your_data'], $_POST);
  // '<pre></pre>' formats array output for html
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($result);
  echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no matching keys and values in both the arrays!
That is why you are getting the whole array returned in the $result variable.

I have explained why this happens below:

### array_diff_assoc

`array_diff_assoc` compares both the **keys** and **values** in the first array to the second array. The keys and values which are present in the *first array* but not in the **second array** is returned to the `$result`

For example

```
<?php

$array1 = array("a" => "apple", "b" => "banana", "c" => "mango");
$array2 = array("a" => "apple",  "b" => "banana", "c" => "mango");
$result = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);
print_r($result)
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( )
```

If you now compare $array2 with $array1

```
<?php
$result = array_diff_assoc($array2, $array1);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Output:

`Array ( [d] => salad )`

As you can see the only non-matching key and value is `"d" => "salad"`

Now let's try this:

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "apple", "b" => "banana", "c" => "mango");
$array2 = array("m" => "apple",  "n" => "banana", "o" => "mango");
$result = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);
print_r($result)
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [a] => apple [b] => banana [c] => mango )
```

As you can see the values are same in both the arrays but the keys are different, so the $array1 gets returned to the $result. So you have to use `array_diff()`, if you want to compare the **values only**.

## array_diff

`array_diff` compares only the values in the array. Now lets try the above same example again!

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "apple", "b" => "banana", "c" => "mango");
$array2 = array("m" => "apple",  "n" => "banana", "o" => "mango");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
print_r($result)
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( )
```

Here the keys are different but the values are same so all results are matching, so empty array is returned!

## Conclusion to your problem

Since you tried both array_diff() and array_diff_assoc(), both of your arrays neither have same values nor both same key and value therefore the whole array in the first argument gets returned in both the cases!

I think you have to use some other method to compare them!

[Edit: You could compare the the $row and $_POST using array_diff() as mentioned under the comment of the question]
References:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: this does not solve the problem. the php functions are used properly, it is the arrays that are not being populated correctly. '$_SESSION['your_data']' has no data

Answer (score -1):

After going through some solutions provided by community members, I edited my code and it worked. My code now looks like this;

```
<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                                  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
                                  $query = "SELECT * FROM updatetest WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
                                      $select_users= mysqli_query($db, $query);
                                      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_users, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                $user_info['name'] =  $row['name'];
                                $user_info['phone'] =  $row['phone'];
                                $user_info['dob'] =  $row['dob'];
                                $user_info['email'] =  $row['email'];
                                $user_info['address_line_1'] = $row['address_line_1'];
                                 $user_info['address_line_2'] =  $row['address_line_2'];
                                 $user_info['town_city'] =  $row['town_city'];
                                 $user_info['county'] =  $row['county'];
                                 $user_info['postcode'] =  $row['postcode'];
                               //  $your_data[] = $user_info;
                                $_SESSION['your_data'] = $user_info;
                                          
                                      }

                                 }
                                ?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $dob = $_POST['dob'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $address_line_1 = $_POST['address_line_1'];
  $town_city = $_POST['town_city'];
  $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];

  $result = array_diff_assoc($_POST, $_SESSION['your_data']);
  // '<pre></pre>' formats array output for html
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($result);
  echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

Note: $result = array_diff_assoc($_POST, $_SESSION['your_data']). The order was reversed, to get the difference.